# AppleScript : How do I delete a POSIX path?

Tags: applescript

I am trying to clear out a shell script file if it exists but I keep running into the errors.

```
tell application "System Events"
    set fileList to POSIX path of disk items of mdFolder
end tell



-->check to see if there is a shell script in the destination folder

repeat with i from 1 to count of every item in fileList
    set thisFile to item i of fileList
    set oasd to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "/"
    set fileName to last text item of thisFile

    if fileName is equal to "ditaShell.sh" then
        tell application "System Events" to delete thisFile
    end if
end repeat

tell application "Finder"

-->create new file for shell script
make new file at mdFolder with properties {name:"ditaShell.sh"}
display dialog "Created new file"

end tell
```

I get this error message:

```
System Events got an error: Can’t make "/Users/xxxxxxxxx/Desktop/DITAConversions/Input/ditaShell.sh" into type disk item.
```

Comment: I solved it, work smarter, not harder. : )

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, was overthinking the problem:

```
tell application "Finder"

delete (every file of folder mdFolder whose name is "ditaShell.sh")

-->create new file for shell script
make new file at mdFolder with properties {name:"ditaShell.sh"}
display dialog "Created new file"
```

end tell

Comment: It makes more sense to `delete the file named "ditaShell.sh" in the folder mdFolder`, rather than `delete every file...`.  But instead of deleting the original, you could choose to scrub its contents instead, which you can do once you obtain the path to `ditaShell.sh`, then using `set eof of "path/to/ditaShell.sh" to 0` (replacing `path/to/ditaShell.sh` with its path or a variable containing its path).